# How to exclude a C++ code directory from build in Android Studio/gradle?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to exclude specific directories from my build, in Android Studio 2.1.2, gradle 2.10. Here's the build.gradle file I have now:

```
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = 'com.android.gl2jni'
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 5
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }
    ndk {
        platformVersion = 9
        moduleName = 'gl2jni'
        toolchain = 'clang'
        stl = 'gnustl_static'
        cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-Wall', '-Wc++11-narrowing'])
        ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'GLESv2'])
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }

    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/KataPlatform']
                    exclude 'src/main/jni/KataPlatform/Linux'
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

The exclude directive appears to have no effect, as the build happily dives into the subfolder and begins generating errors. How do I convince it to skip over all of the files inside that Linux subfolder?

Comment: Looks like this is still an open issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64957

Comment: I'm baffled that a build system would not have a correct implementation of something this fundamental. Would it be a reasonable course of action to simply walk away from gradle and configure an old style Ant build instead?

Comment: The lack/late support for the NDK in Android Studio has been baffling me since they announced the new build system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that gradle is trying to exclude "src/main/jni/KataPlatform/src/main/jni/KataPlatform/Linux".  After you set your sourceDirs, your excludes should be relative to that.  Try changing your exclude to just 'Linux' like in the following code snippet:

```
sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/KataPlatform']
                exclude 'Linux'
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't set a srcDirs it will default to 'src/main/jni' so changing your code to the following should work too:

```
sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                exclude 'KataPlatform/Linux'
            }
        }


    }
}
```